# Unexpected behaviour of fragment when we choose dont keep activity in developer option

Tags: android, android-fragments

when select option don't keep activity in developer eeven i had declare public empty constructor in fragment i am getting following issue.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity         
ComponentInfo{com.example.app/io.example.view.s.TestActivity}:   
android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: 
Unable to instantiate fragment io.example.view.s.TestActivity$TestFragment: 
make sure class name exists, is public,
and has an empty constructor that is public
```

I face this exception when i go from one activity to another activity 
  and i pressed device back.[image]

Comment: Does your `TestFragment` have public default constructor (`public TestFragment() {}`)?

Comment: Yes i had declared it.